# What does 'provides money' mean in context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

While reading this text I understand all words but I can not imagine what is going on factually. What is '12000' and what does 'provides money' mean here? Does it mean to give them money or to help them earn money?

> The festival is not just about having a good time either. It is also a money-making event for Marlinton and Pocahontas County.
>
> “It’s close to a $2 million economic impact,” says Wilfong. “The population of Pocahontas County is just slightly over 8,500 people, and they get about **12,000** for the event.”
>
> Wilfong added that the festival **provides money** for all businesses in the area, such as fuel businesses, hotels, store owners and restaurants.

Source: [West Virginia Cook-off Celebrates Unusual Foods](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/west-virginia-cook-off-celebrates-unusual-foods/4600987.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wilfong is pointing out that 12,000 people will attend the festival, and because the local poulation is only 8,500 that means a lot of visitors are from outside the county. The visitors spend money on fuel, accommodation, and food so local businesses benefit greatly.

The last sentence would be clearer as

> Wilfong added that the festival **generates income** for all
>   businesses in the area . . .